# Rails/SQL How do I get different workers to work on different records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, multithreading, postgresql

I have (for argument sake) 1000 records and 10 Heroku workers running. 
I want to have each worker work on a different set of records..

What I've got right now is quite good, but not quite complete.

```
sql = 'update products set status = 2 where id in 
         (select id from products where status = 1 limit (100) ) return *'
records = connection.execute(sql)
```

This works rather well.. I get get 100 records and at the same time, I make sure my other workers don't get the same 100.. 
If I throw it in a while loop then even if I have 20000 records and 2 workers, eventually they will all get processed.

My issue is if there's a crash or exception then the 100 records look like their being processed by another worker but they aren't.
I can't use transaction, because the other selects will pick up the same records.

**My question**
What strategies do others use to have many workers working on the same dataset, but different records.

I know this is a conversational question... I'd put it as community wiki, but I don't see that ability any more.

Comment: Read this article on process partitioning https://gist.github.com/2374465

Answer (score 2):

Building a task queue in a RDBMS is annoyingly hard. I recommend using a queueing system that's designed for the job instead.

Check out [PGQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGQ_Tutorial), Celery, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [queue_classic](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic) by Heroku to schedule jobs stored in a Postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this it would be something other than a db-side queue.  It sounds like standard client processing but you really want is parallel processing of the result set.

The simplest solution might be to do what you are doing but lock them on the client side, and divide them between workers there (spinlocks etc).  You can then commit the transaction and re-run after these have finished processing.

The difficulty is that if you have records you are processing for things that are supposed to happen outside the server, and there is a crash, you never really know what records were processed.  It is safer to rollback probably, but just keep that in mind.